# (not (A XOR B)) XOR C breakdown

Tags: boolean-logic

How can I expand this equation? I know that A XOR B is the same as (A * NOT B) + ((NOT A) *B), so would the (not(A XOR B)) be ((NOT A) * B) + (A * NOT B)? Even so, how would I include the second part as well? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: clarify your use of + and * for and and or. It varies from discipline to discipline.

Comment: If a and b are equal, the whole left side of the rightmost xor goes to 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
(NOT (A XOR B)) XOR C
```

means

```
((NOT (A AND (NOT B)) OR (B AND (NOT A))) AND NOT C) OR (C AND ((A AND (NOT B)) OR (B AND (NOT A))))
```

Operator1 `XOR` Operator2 requires, that only one (exact one) of the operators is `true` so that the result is `true`. That means `(A XOR B)` translates as you said to `(A AND (NOT B)) OR (B AND (NOT A))`. This result is negated on the left side of your formula and `XOR` ed with C. That means, on the left side there is an implicit NOT C while on the right side there is a implicit `NOT NOT ((A AND (NOT B)) OR (B AND (NOT A)))`. The `NOT NOT` cancels itself out, so that only `(A AND (NOT B)) OR (B AND (NOT A))` remains there.